# Is a VL3030 coin cell battery a suitable replacement for a ML2430?

Tags: batteries, load, standard, capacity

I am attempting to replace a battery in my electronic compass and im supposed to use an ML2430, however  this is proving to be hard to get hold of and expensive.

I'm concidering using a VL 3032/HF5N as an alternative. I can make the difference in sizes work but am not quite sure if the electrical properties would fit. They both have a voltage V = 3 V and nominal capacity of 100 mAh. However, the ML2430 has a standard charge/discharge current of 0.5 mA whereas the continuous standard load of the VL3032 is 0.2 mA.

Are these equivalent and if so, will the difference cause issues? And should these components be interchangable?

Comment: That would depend on the device which you have not mentioned anything about. The manual or manufacturer of the device would know what are suitable replacements, we don't know what parameters of the battery are important for the device.

Comment: VL3030?  Are you sure?

Comment: Hey so its a VL3032 not VL3032

Comment: And the device its for is a raymarine tacktick microcompass but the manufacture is fairly cagey about awnsering questions and would much rather you buy a new compass rather than replace the battery in the old ones

Comment: Do you know if continuose standard load is the same as the standard charge/discharge rates?

Comment: sorry charge/discharge current

Comment: did you use VL3032? I'm also looking forward to replace battery in my TackTick and I came across your topic. btw - I found one company that sells ML2430 in normal price in Europe. Point is that delivery time is pretty much long - up to 12 weeks. I already ordered 2 pcs, as they cost about 10€. http://www.batimex.pl/towar.php?idtowaru=2398

Comment: Hi yes I did in the end and seemed to work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The price difference may be a reflection of supplier profit or material costs but not performance but the big difference is coin cell volume ratio. ~2:1

**I see these rechargeable coin cells as almost identical performance** yet use different marketing graphs.

The most important one spec initially is that they have the same Capacity and ESR.
The second might be your 1st priority and that is longevity.  In this regard both follow Peukert's Law and both seem to be identical.

The important thing to see here is if your charge cycles.

- at 100% DoD both get 4Ah,  net total in their "life time."
- at 50% DoD both get 5Ah
- at 10% DoD both get ~10Ah

Therefore both are equivalent, even though the Panasonic you say is cheaper and better availability.

Panasonic VL3032 volume  \$\pi *15^2*3.2=720 mm^3\$  is more conservative (lower E-density)
FDK . . . ML2430 volume  \$\pi *12^2*3.0=430 mm^3\$

Comment: Thankyou that was very helpful

Comment: @RossAnderson Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

If you compare the datasheets of Sanyo ML2430 and Panasonic VL3032 they show a notable difference in the specified standard charging voltages.

ML2430: 3.1V +-0.15V

VL3032: 3.25 ... 3.55V in the specification, and a further hint in the handling guides: If a fixed-(voltage?)-charging method is used, please adhere to specified charging voltage. Guaranteed voltage is 3.4V +-0.15V in the Temperature range.

To make a good decision one could measure the typical operating current of your device and more importantly the used charging voltage.

I'd suspect if the charging of the original ML2430 takes place at 3.1V it could take longer to charge the VL3032 to full.